# Replacing filename placeholder with file contents in sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed, include, cat

I'm trying to write a basic script to compile HTML file includes. 
The premise goes like this:

I have 3 files

**test.html**

```
<div>
   @include include1.html

   <div>content</div>

   @include include2.html
</div>
```

**include1.html**

```
<span>
   banana
</span>
```

**include2.html**

```
<span>
   apple
</span>
```

My desired output would be:

**output.html**

```
<div>
   <span>
      banana
   </span>

   <div>content</div>

   <span>
      apple
   </span>
</div>
```

I've tried the following:

1. `sed "s|@include \(.*)|$(cat \1)|" test.html >output.html`
   This returns `cat: 1: No such file or directory`
2. `sed "s|@include \(.*)|cat \1|" test.html >output.html`
   This runs but gives:

   **output.html**

   ```
   <div>
      cat include1.html

      <div>content</div>

      cat include2.html
   </div>
   ```

Any ideas on how to run `cat` inside `sed` using group substitution? Or perhaps another solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote this [15-20 years ago](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.awk/GPgPMi4u1BA/VpOBThRJ40AJ) to recursively include files and it's included in [the article I wrote about how/when to use getline](http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline) under "Applications" then "d)". I tweaked it now to work with your specific "@include" directive, provide indenting to match the "@include" indentation, and added a safeguard against infinite recursion (e.g. file A includes file B and file B includes file A):

```
$ cat tst.awk
function read(file,indent) {
    if ( isOpen[file]++ ) {
        print "Infinite recursion detected" | "cat>&2"
        exit 1
    }

    while ( (getline < file) > 0) {
        if ($1 == "@include") {
             match($0,/^[[:space:]]+/)
             read($2,indent substr($0,1,RLENGTH))
        } else {
             print indent $0
        }
    }
    close(file)

    delete isOpen[file]
}

BEGIN{
   read(ARGV[1],"")
   exit
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk test.html
<div>
   <span>
      banana
   </span>

   <div>content</div>

   <span>
      apple
   </span>
</div>
```

Note that if `include1.html` itself contained a `@include ...` directive then it'd be honored too, and so on. Look:

```
$ for i in test.html include?.html; do printf -- '-----\n%s\n' "$i"; cat "$i"; done
-----
test.html
<div>
   @include include1.html

   <div>content</div>

   @include include2.html
</div>
-----
include1.html
<span>
   @include include3.html
</span>
-----
include2.html
<span>
   apple
</span>
-----
include3.html
<div>
   @include include4.html
</div>
-----
include4.html
<span>
   grape
</span>
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk test.html
<div>
   <span>
      <div>
         <span>
            grape
         </span>
      </div>
   </span>

   <div>content</div>

   <span>
      apple
   </span>
</div>
```

With a non-GNU awk I'd expect it to fail after about 20 levels of recursion with a "too many open files" error so get gawk if you need to go deeper than that or you'd have to write your own file management code.

Comment: This is really an awesome awk script for recursive include functionality ++

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU sed, you can use [the `e` flag](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-s-command_002c-option-flags) to the `s` command, which executes the current pattern space as a shell command and replaces it with the output:

```
$ sed 's/@include/cat/e' test.html
<div>
<span>
   banana
</span>

   <div>content</div>

<span>
   apple
</span>
</div>
```

Notice that this doesn't take care of indentation, as the included files don't have any. An  HTML prettifier like [Tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org) can help you further for this:

```
$ sed 's/@include/cat/e' test.html | tidy -iq --show-body-only yes
<div>
  <span>banana</span>
  <div>
    content
  </div><span>apple</span>
</div>
```

GNU has a command to read a file, [`r`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-r-_0028read-file_0029-command), but the filename can't be generated on the fly.

---

As [Ed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) points out in his comment, this is vulnerable to shell command injection: if you have something like

```
@include $(date)
```

you'll notice that the `date` command was actually run. This can be prevented, but the conciseness if the original solution is out the window then:

```
sed 's|@include \(.*\)|cat "$(/usr/bin/printf "%q" '\''\1'\'')"|e' test.html
```

This still replaces `@include` with `cat`, but additionally wraps the rest of the line into a command substitution with `printf "%q"`, so a line such as

```
@include include1.html
```

becomes

```
cat "$(/usr/bin/printf "%q" 'include1.html')"
```

before being executed as a command. This expands to

```
cat include1.html
```

but if the file were named `$(date)`, it becomes

```
cat '$(date)'
```

(note the single quotes), preventing the injected command from being executed.

Because `s///e` seems to use `/bin/sh` as its shell, you can't rely on Bash's `%q` format specification in `printf` to exist, hence the absolute path to the `printf` binary. For readability, I've changed the `/` delimiters of the `s` command to `|` (so I don't have to escape `\/usr\/bin\/printf`).

Lastly, the quoting mess around `\1` is to get a single quote into a single quoted string: `'\''` becomes `'`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `bash` script that uses a regex to detect line starting with `@include` and grabs include filename using a capture group:

```
re="@include +([^[:space:]]+)"

while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ $re ]] && cat "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" || echo "$line"
done < test.html
```

```
<div>
<span>
   banana
</span>

   <div>content</div>

<span>
   apple
</span>
</div>
```

**Alternatively** you may use this `awk` script to do the same:

```
awk '$1 == "@include"{system("cat " $2); next} 1' test.html
```

Comment: I'm surprised you'd suggest a shell loop ([why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)) and that awk script won't necessarily produce the system() output in the expected order wrt the rest of the main input file.